# wrong exit return value using %rdi as argument

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, att

I just wrote the following code to compute the magic sum of 2^3 + 2^5. I have a couple of questions.

1.In the x86_64 calling convention arguments are passed in registers %rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8 and %r9. However when i tried to call exit with value in %rdi, compiled it and then did `echo $?`it gave me value of 0. If i instead transfer value to %rbx, like below it gives me correct result.

2.Initially i had the code that does exit with a label `exit:` at end of file and i did `jmp exit` instead of the three last lines in _start. That gave me a segmentation fault. Why?

3.What do i need to do to get base and power from the command line? Where is argv?

```
.data
.globl _start
_start:
        movq $2, %rdi
        movq $3, %rsi
        call power
        pushq %rax

        movq $2, %rdi
        movq $5, %rsi
        call power

        popq %rdi

        addq %rax, %rdi

        movq $1, %rax
        movq %rdi, %rbx 
        int $0x80

power:
        pushq %rbp
        movq %rsp, %rbp
        movq %rsi, %rcx
        decq %rcx
        subq $8, %rsp
        movq %rdi, -8(%rbp)

loop_power:
        movq -8(%rbp), %rax
        imulq %rdi, %rax
        movq %rax, -8(%rbp)
        loop loop_power

exit_power:
        movq -8(%rbp), %rax
        movq %rbp, %rsp
        popq %rbp
        retq
```

update:

```
.data
.text
.globl _start
_start:
        movq $2, %rdi
        movq $3, %rsi
        call power
        pushq %rax

        movq $2, %rdi
        movq $5, %rsi
        call power

        popq %rdi

        addq %rax, %rdi

        jmp exit

power:
        pushq %rbp
        movq %rsp, %rbp
        movq %rsi, %rcx
        decq %rcx
        subq $8, %rsp
        movq %rdi, -8(%rbp)

loop_power:
        movq -8(%rbp), %rax
        imulq %rdi, %rax
        movq %rax, -8(%rbp)
        loop loop_power

exit_power:
        movq -8(%rbp), %rax
        movq %rbp, %rsp
        popq %rbp
        retq

exit:
        movq $60, %rax
        syscall
```

Comment: It appears you are creating code that bypasses the _C_ library since you are using `_start` as an entry point. When doing this you can't use `retq` to return since there is no return point on the stack to. You'll want to use a `syscall` to exit your program instead. And you should really use `syscall` rather than `int 0x80` in 64-bit code. The arguments when you use `_start` as an entry point are passed in via the OS on the stack but differently than what you expect in _C_. `(%RSP)` is the number of args `8(%RSP)` is pointer to first prog argument, `16(%RSP)` is the second etc.

Comment: See page 29 (_Stack State_ in section 3.4/Process Initialization) of the [System V 64-bit ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) regarding the program parameters when using `_start`

Comment: You should also put your code in the `.text` section, not the `.data` section.

Comment: Information on the 64-bit Linux _SYSCALL_ convention can be found here: http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64

Comment: Iam only using retq in the power function when i want to leave that function and for that function there will be return address on the stack, it get's pushed when i call from _start. Aren't the last 3 lines of _start already a syscall? I thought .globl _start was already doing the,linking, what do i have to do then?

Comment: `int 0x80` is the old style 32-bit system call. In 64-bit the preferred mechanism is the actual _SYSCALL_ instruction. `int 0x80` is limited in that any call that may require passing a 64-bit pointer will not always work  The calling convention (and the system call numbers) are different between _SYSCALL_ and `int 0x80`. `int 0x80` doesn't pass the return value for `sys_exit` in _RDI_, it passes it in _EBX_. This can be found in [this chart](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html) for `int 0x80` Linux calls

Comment: `.globl _start` just says that the label `_start` is visible to other modules (object files/libraries etc)

Comment: One thing i don't understand is why _start  bypasses the C library. That's the only method i know what other options do i have?

Comment: You can rename `_start` to `main` then use _GCC_ to do the assembling and linking. _GCC_ happens to do the drudgery of linking in the _C_ library. You could then assemble and link to an executable with something like `gcc -m64 compute.s -o compute` . _GCC_ will pass `.s` files through to GAS (Gnu assembler) automagically.

Comment: Tried to give it arguments in command line and like you said at _start (%rsp) had the number of args, 8(%rsp) had first argument, but not the others!

Comment: That ABI file comes up a lot. When i look at it's a bit overwhelming but i have to make an effort... Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I'd have to see your code to know why 16(%rsp) and higher didn't have **pointers** to the individual parameters passed as arguments. Sounds like a coding bug, not a system bug. Understanding the ABIs can be daunting, but if you are writing 64-bit programs I recommend the [64-bit Linux System V ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) as a reference. In 64-bit code do not use `int 0x80` to avoid problems  instead use _SYSCALL_ instruction. [This table](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64) created by Ryan Chapman is a good one for 64-bit SYSCALL

Comment: As for 8(%rsp) it is a pointer to the first parameter on the command line, which happens to be the program file name. A pointer to the first argument after the program name should be 16(%rsp), the next being 24(%rsp), and so on. Remember these are pointers to strings. So you'd have to convert ascii strings representing numbers into integer values for computation. Such conversion doesn't happen automatically. If you do link to the _C_ library you can take advantage of functions like `atoi` and `atol` to do the conversions.